# Stacking a gradient cone on body background

Tags: css

I'm trying to stack a gradient cone on my body background colour but to no avail. The gradient disappears behind the body background colour.

What's the best way to stack these too? Putting the cone in a div and using a z-index didn't work for some reason.

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
  body {
    color: white;
    background: qdark;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.cone {
  position: absolute;
  width: 933.36px;
  height: 631.19px;
  left: -41.74px;
  top: -81.43px;

  background: conic-gradient(
    from 164.14deg at 61.44% 127.33%,
    #051523 -135.65deg,
    #081a29 144.52deg,
    #3771a4 151.32deg,
    #48bed3 158.87deg,
    #5968ee 168.95deg,
    #a3aaf1 174.33deg,
    #5262c7 175.76deg,
    #c158d7 179.56deg,
    #ec9f92 195.06deg,
    #e45784 196.86deg,
    #8a63b0 208.42deg,
    #443782 216.35deg,
    #051523 224.35deg,
    #081a29 504.52deg
  );
  filter: blur(50px);
  transform: rotate(-0.99deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rely on pseudo element:

```css
html {
  background: blue;
}

html:before {
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  inset: -20%;

  background: conic-gradient(
    from 164.14deg at 61.44% 127.33%,
    #051523 -135.65deg,
    #081a29 144.52deg,
    #3771a4 151.32deg,
    #48bed3 158.87deg,
    #5968ee 168.95deg,
    #a3aaf1 174.33deg,
    #5262c7 175.76deg,
    #c158d7 179.56deg,
    #ec9f92 195.06deg,
    #e45784 196.86deg,
    #8a63b0 208.42deg,
    #443782 216.35deg,
    #051523 224.35deg,
    #081a29 504.52deg
  );
  filter: blur(50px);
  transform: rotate(-0.99deg);
}
```